# VLC sensitive speed up shortcut doesn't work

Tags: vlc-media-player

I changed the shortcut from the tools->preferences->shortcut buttons. Anything changed there doesn't effect anything. It doesn't work. I tried to change my layout etc

Answer (score 0):

Restarting was needed. When I restart the VLC, the changes was working. I think there has to be a message that says "restarting is needed to make the changes work"

Comment: You'd need to ask VLC themselves about any message, but yes, almost all changes in VLC require you to relaunch the app. It has always been this way, on all platforms.